# How to generate a cartoon of a face

Tags: image-processing, generative-art

I want to use *Mathematica* to generate a cartoon of a face. For example, some thing like this:

[image]

I think it can be done using *Mathematica*, but I really don't know how to do it. How can it be done, and what kind of a cartoon can *Mathematica* generate?

Comment: Have a look at `MeanShiftFilter` to get you started.

Comment: Havw a look at Michael Trott's [post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/) on the Wolfram Blog.

Comment: Also, note that Mathematica won't zip up the guy's hoodie for you. The pictures don't match.

Comment: @Verbeia I know that. what I am looking at is the face only.

Comment: @m_goldberg incredible work in Blog. thanks.

Comment: http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~mtzhao/research/nprbookchapter/zhao_Portraits.pdf

Comment: the work of mt zhao is wonderful!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an idea based on `MeanShiftFilter`:

```
start = ImageCrop[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Girl3"}], 200, Left];
step1 = MeanShiftFilter[start, 3, 0.05, MaxIterations -> 10]
```

[image]

```
step2 = Binarize[ColorNegate[DerivativeFilter[step1, {0, 1}]], 0.95]
```

[image]

```
ImageMultiply[step1, step2]
```

[image]

Obviously you can play with filters to get a different outline effect. Here is a quick `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{colorversion = 
    MeanShiftFilter[start, ms1, ms2, MaxIterations -> 10]}, 
  ImageMultiply[colorversion, 
   ImageMultiply[
    Binarize[ColorNegate[DerivativeFilter[colorversion, {0, 1}]], v1],
     Binarize[ColorNegate[DerivativeFilter[colorversion, {1, 0}]], 
     h1]]] ], {ms1, 1, 6, 1}, {ms2, 0.01, 0.1}, {v1, 0.8, 0.999}, {h1, 0.8, 0.999}]
```

[image]